# ELF Header Size Greater than 52 bytes

Tags: c, elf

According to the given Elf32_Ehdr structure (page9) in the link [elf-format](http://flint.cs.yale.edu/cs422/doc/ELF_Format.pdf)  elf header size should be 52 bytes and fixed. But there is also field e_ehsize and can be greater than 52 bytes. In where defined those extra bytes until first section header starts ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be aware that the ELF Header is usually 52 bytes on 32 bit machine, and 64 bytes on a 64 bit machine. 
The old specification [1] doesn't include the 64 bit header in its description. This might be the specification that you have been using. 
[1] http://www.skyfree.org/linux/references/ELF_Format.pdf

You can check the 64 bit ELF headers accessing the document [2]. 
[2] ftp://www.linux-mips.org/pub/linux/mips/doc/ABI/elf64-2.4.pdf

The difference between the 32 and 64-bit ELF header is ahead:

```
 typedef struct{
      ........                 //            struct Elf32_Ehdr
    Elf64_Addr      e_entry;   //[8 bytes]  Elf32_Addr [4 bytes]
    Elf64_Off       e_phoff;   //[8 bytes]  Elf32_Off  [4 bytes]
    Elf64_Off       e_shoff;   //[8 bytes]  Elf32_Off  [4 bytes]
      .......
} Elf64_Ehdr;
```

The size difference is therefore (4*3)=12 bytes from the 32 to 64-bit ELF header. Also notice that the header might include extra bits at the end as indicated by the specification.
When parsing the ELF binary, make sure you read the first 16 bytes first, to identify if the file is a 32 or 64-bit elf.

Answer (score 2):

As it says, also on page 9:

> Some object file control structures can grow, because the ELF header contains their actual sizes.  **If the object file format changes**, a program may encounter control structures that are larger or smaller than expected.  Programs might therefore ignore ‘‘extra’’ information.  The treatment of ‘‘missing’’  information depends on context and will be specified **when and if extensions are defined**.

(emphasis added). Nothing defines the semantics of any extra bytes, currently; they would comprise an extension. Furthermore the text implies that if you find a file with an `Elf32_Ehdr` section longer than 52 bytes, you can safely ignore the extra bytes.

Comment: in some cases it is fixed 52 bytes when i could not notice... There are strings in the extra bytes such as section names etc. i am not sure if they are defined somewhere or not

Comment: thanks @davmac you are right!  but through my trials i remember fixed 52 bytes that should come from linker or compiler settings that do not put those extra bytes